# Notepad++ - автоматическая расстановка переносов строк в html

Tags: html, строки, notepad++

Подскажите, как в notepad++ расставить автоматически переносы строк (может есть плагин специальный?), чтобы код вида:

```
 <html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>
```

Стал:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Дальше к нему можно будет применить плагин IdentByFold для автоматической расстановки табуляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), хороший вариант. Может, кому поможет в дальнейшем - превращаем код в удобный читаемый вид:

1. Проводим замену > на >\r\n в режиме  extended search mode;
2. Проводим замену < на \r\n< в режиме  extended search mode;
3. Убираем пустые строчки через edit->Line Operations->Remove Empty Lines и edit->Line Operations->Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank Characters);
4. Используем плагин IdentByFold

На выходе удобный читаемый код.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить `>` на `>\r\n` (возможно, потребуется режим extended search mode).

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался в данное проблеме.

- Заходите в "Опции" →
- "Горячие клавиши" →
- Вводите в *Filter* "Перенос по словам", такая функция есть →
- Выбираете комбинацию, к примеру, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> →
- Сохраняете изменение, вставляете нужный текст в NotePad++ и на клавиатуре клавишами активируете команду переноса по словам.

Готово!

Теперь текст переносится по словам, а не за рамки и теперь не нужно прокручивать вперёд настолько, насколько текст в одной строке.

Comment: похоже это дает не совсем тот результат, о котором говорится в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Выделяем текст, нажимаем ctrl + I

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ -- что будет этой комбинацией клавиш достигнуто.

Answer (score -1):

Вот, и ненужно ничего изобретать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]